# SQL varbinary IP compare

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that stores IPs as `varbinary(16)`. So '10.240.200.9' will be stored as 0x0AF0C809.

I'm writing a stored procedure which has to create dynamic sql due to the nature of the input variables. One of the input variables is an IP address.

Let's just take the previously mentioned IP and its hex. When I run the query below, it gives me the following error

> The data types varchar and varbinary are incompatible in the add operator.

I understand that it's happening due to `@hex` being concatenated to a `nvarchar` string.

I'm trying to make this SQL work

```
set @sql = 'select * from [table] where ip = ' + [hexvalue]
```

Comment: Not solvng your problem just an observation. Don't you need an equal sign after ip?

Comment: Yes boss. Sorry about that. I had a bigger query but SO wasn't allowing me to paste in everything so I just typed in what I thought was relevant. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitely cast the value to a compatible type such as `varchar`.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('test' AS varbinary(4)) AS varchar(4)) + 'test'
```

With your example:

```
set @sql = 'select * from [table] where ip = ''' + CAST([hexvalue] AS varchar(16)) + ''''
```

Comment: You should always declare `VARCHAR` with a length. (Well, also `VARBINARY`)

Comment: This also won't work since it's missing the `=` after `ip` and you are not concatenating the extra single quotes needed

Comment: Yes the statement was taken from a bigger piece of code. SO didn't allow me to include it.

Comment: @Lamak, I took the OP's statement as is and stated in the answer that the statement is wrong already. The question has nothing to do with the validity of the statement and it isin't relevant.

Comment: well, why not take the opportunity of fixing such errors?. They are simple ones, and I see no reason why would you leave them in your answer with a note that the statement is wrong instead

Comment: @Lamak You just assumed that checking for equality was the correct statement and you were right, but you could as well have been wrong. I prefered not to base my answser on any assumptions. The only real fact was that the statement had a syntax error. Anyway, I corrected it now ;)

Comment: if varbinary(16) = 0x0AF0C809 and you cast it as a varchar(16) it will result in: select * from [table] where ip = 'ðÈ' won't it?

Comment: @Bozman, it depends what you want I believe. `DECLARE @hex varbinary(16) = CONVERT(varbinary(16), '10.240.200.9'); SELECT CAST(@hex AS varchar(16));` correctly selects `'10.240.200.9'`. However if you want the varbinary value as string you are right.

Answer (score 1):

although that answer will convert it to varchar i do not believe the output is what you are looking for. this will work if your input is a varbinary(16) parameter

```
declare @s varbinary(16) = 0x0AF0C809
set @sql = 'select * from [table] where ip = ' + + UPPER(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@s))
```